# How do I create a spatial index in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, arcgis, spatial-index, mapinfo

I have a table with 3 columns, `PrimaryKey(int)`, `latitude(decimal 9,6)` and `longitude(decimal 9,6)`.

I've imported a live view into mapinfo 10.5 using its DBMS connection but can't seem to make the table mappable or "create points' to map the coordinates.

I right click to add a new index in MS management studio but the only index types it brings up are clustered, non clustered and xml, no option for spatial.

Answer (score 1):

A spatial index can be created only on a column of type `geometry` or `geography`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964740.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a new column (NEWGEOGRAPHY) with a datatype of geometry or geography.  Next, update that column with something like this:

UPDATE tablename
SET NEWGEOGRAPHY =
geography::STGeomFromText(POINT(LATCol LONGCol), 4326)

Then you should be able to create the Spatial index on this table using that column.